# problems creating sqlite tables

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im trying to create two tables in one database,using sqlite on android studio.
after creating the 1st table an error occurred while creating the second table (3rd column does not exists)

```
package com.mbsps.doctorhelper;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public String dateReq;

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="DBDoctorshelper";
    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_Emails ="emails";
    // Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_NAME ="FirstName";
    private static final String KEY_LASTNAME ="LastName";
    private static final String KEY_AGE= "Age";
    private static final String KEY_DATENTIME= "DatenTime";
    private static final String KEY_LOCATION= "Location";
    private static final String KEY_ALLERGIES= "Allergies";
    private static final String KEY_MEDICINE= "Medicine";
    private static final String KEY_REFERREBY= "ReferedBy";
    public static final String CREATE_QUERY =
            "CREATE TABLE "+ ContractUser.UserInfo.TABLE_NAME + " ("+ ContractUser.UserInfo.USER_EMAIL+" TEXT,"+ ContractUser.UserInfo.USER_PASSWORD+" TEXT);";
    public static final String CREATE_QUERY2=
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Emails+"(" + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_LASTNAME  + " TEXT," + KEY_AGE + " TEXT," + KEY_DATENTIME + " DATE," + KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT," + KEY_ALLERGIES + " TEXT," + KEY_MEDICINE + " TEXT);";

    public DBHandler(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "Database created/ opened.");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);

        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "Table Doc_info created");
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY2);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "Table emails created");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ ContractUser.UserInfo.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_Emails);

}
```

Please i need help

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?

Comment: no duplicate, error on creating second table, exactly on he 3rd field

Comment: Please recheck your query. For example, your missing space in `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_Emails);`

Comment: It was the Database_version, i change it to int not final int then on creating second table, than i increment its value by one.